# How to do this Class inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, tornado

I have a Python/[Tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado) application that responds to HTTP requests with the following 3 classes:

```
import tornado.web
class MyClass1(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    x = 1
    y = 2

    def my_method1(self):
        print "Hello World"


class MyClass2(MyClass1):

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        #Do Something 1
        pass

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def post(self):
        #Do Something 2
        pass


class MyClass3(MyClass2):
    pass
```

I would like all instances `MyClass2` to have an instance variable `m` set to the integer 3. But any instances of `MyClass3` should over-ride that and have `m` set to the integer 4. How can I do it?

I tried adding the following constructors to `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` respectively, but then when I try to create an instance of `MyClass3`, I get the following error: `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`

MyClass2.**init**():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.m = 3 # This value will be overridden by a subclass
```

MyClass3.**init**():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.m = 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tornado.web.RequestHandler` already has a `__init__` method and Tornado expects it to take two arguments (plus the `self` argument of a bound method). Your overridden versions don't take these.

Update your `__init__` methods to take *arbitrary extra arguments* and pass these on via [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class MyClass2(MyClass1):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.m = 3

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        #Do Something 1
        pass

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def post(self):
        #Do Something 2
        pass


class MyClass3(MyClass2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass3, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.m = 4
```

You could also use the [`RequestHandler.initialize()` method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize) to set up per-request instance variables; you *may* have to use `super()` again to pass on the call to the parent class, if your parent class `initialize()` does *more* work than just set `self.m`.

Answer (score 0):

`ReequestHandler`'s [constructor takes arguments](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler):

```
class RequestHandler(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        ...
```

When you inherit `RequestHandler` you then either:

a) Do not override `__init__` (i.e. do not provide your own constructor)
or
b) If you override `__init__` (provide your own constructor), then your constructor should have the same signature, since the framework will call the constructor.